# how to bind method to variable inside constructor method in class

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, local-storage

while I'm retrieving data using getValue() and binding its value to this.itemList variable in the constructor method inside the class it returns an empty array however there are data in local storage how is the right way to do that?.

```js
class UI {
  constructor() {

    this.storageBudget = UI.getValue(this.BUDGET_LOCAL_STORAGE);
    this.itemList =
      JSON.parse(UI.getValue(this.EXPENSE_LOCAL_STORAGE)) || [];
    this.itemID = 0;
    this.BUDGET_LOCAL_STORAGE = 'BUDGET_LOCAL_STORAGE';
    this.EXPENSE_LOCAL_STORAGE = 'EXPENSE_LOCAL_STORAGE';

  }

  static save(key, value) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }
  static getValue(key) {
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `this.BUDGET_LOCAL_STORAGE` and `this.EXPENSE_LOCAL_STORAGE` in the calls to `UI.getValue()` before you set them. So set those properties before you try to use them.

```js
class UI {
  constructor() {

    this.BUDGET_LOCAL_STORAGE = 'BUDGET_LOCAL_STORAGE';
    this.EXPENSE_LOCAL_STORAGE = 'EXPENSE_LOCAL_STORAGE';
    this.storageBudget = UI.getValue(this.BUDGET_LOCAL_STORAGE);
    this.itemList =
      JSON.parse(UI.getValue(this.EXPENSE_LOCAL_STORAGE)) || [];
    this.itemID = 0;

  }

  static save(key, value) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
  }
  static getValue(key) {
    return localStorage.getItem(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: OMG!! I have spent 2 hrs to solve this issue and didn’t notice this .. thanks so mush .